# How to extract a buffer layer from a vast amount of individual buffers around polygons using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, buffer

I have a vector layer containing nearly 8000 singlepart polygons. It looks like this:
[image]

I want statistics on the area that is further than 2,5m away from any border. I thought I could do this by creating a buffer of 2,5m around all polygons, then extracting the buffer area from the original dataset. I manage to create the buffer, but it is not a separate layer, and the polygons that are created are all multi-part with double lines.

When I select a polygon, I see the lines are overlapping, and I need the buffer lines to be separate polygons. I have tried using the multipart to singlepart tool, but it does not solve the problem. Neither does creating a union between the original layer and the buffer layer.

This is one example - here I have selected one polygon in the buffer layer(the original layer behind with grey lines, the buffer layer with see through background ad red lines, selected polygon marked with blue lines)::
[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the polygons by using the `search by location` option? If you are not able to do this directly maybe try selecting the ones that are within 2.5m and then inverting that selection

Comment: If I could create the buffer as separate polygons I could probably use the search by location, but I think my problems are even more basic as I can even select one singe buffer area by clicking it. I have updated my question to explain the problem better.

Comment: Use negative buffer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track. What I find a bit peculiar is that you don't get a separte layer from your `buffer` function. Have you entered an output feature class in the tool?

**Idea 1:** Try the approach by @FelixIP. Negative Buffers might be what you're after.

**Idea 2:** Another option might be to try to dissolve the buffered polygons (see image below). This should get rid of all the overlapping parts, however, you might loose some detail.

[image: buffer tool]

---

You should receive a separate layer using the buffer tool like this. After that I suggest you try the method proposed by @Hasan Mustafa - `select by location`.